# DynamicReports crosstab report column grouping breaks after calling setDataPreSorted(true)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, crosstab, dynamic-reports

I'm using crosstab report and after applying row and column sorting, it breaks column grouping.
I call setDataPreSorted(true) on crosstab and SortBuilder for row and column:

```
SortBuilder rowSortBuilder = asc(field("rowOrder", Integer.class));
SortBuilder columnSortBuilder = asc(field("colOrder", Integer.class));
report.sortBy(rowSortBuilder, columnSortBuilder)
```

Here's how it supposed to look:
[image]

But the column grouping breaks and it looks like this:
[image]

Here's my full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.Templates;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.asc;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.cmp;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.ctab;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.field;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report;
import static net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.stl;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.SortBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.Components;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.crosstab.CrosstabBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.crosstab.CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.crosstab.CrosstabMeasureBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.crosstab.CrosstabRowGroupBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.StyleBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.Calculation;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalTextAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.PageOrientation;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.PageType;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.VerticalTextAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class CrosstabGroupTest {

    public JasperReportBuilder build() throws DRException {

        JasperReportBuilder report = report();

        // styles
        String reportFont = "Roboto";
        int cellPadding = 3;

        StyleBuilder headerStyleCenter = stl.style().setFontName(reportFont).setFontSize(10).setBold(true)
            .setBorder(stl.pen1Point()).setPadding(cellPadding)
            .setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER)
            .setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.MIDDLE);

        StyleBuilder rowStyleData = stl.style().setFontName(reportFont).setFontSize(10)
                .setBorder(stl.pen1Point()).setPadding(cellPadding)
                .setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setVerticalTextAlignment(VerticalTextAlignment.MIDDLE);

        // row groups
        CrosstabRowGroupBuilder<String> rowGroupItem = ctab.rowGroup("product", String.class).setShowTotal(false)
                .setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData).setHeaderWidth(120);
        CrosstabRowGroupBuilder<String> rowGroupUnit = ctab.rowGroup("unit", String.class).setShowTotal(false)
                .setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData).setHeaderWidth(50);
        CrosstabRowGroupBuilder<String> rowGroupDate = ctab.rowGroup("date", String.class).setShowTotal(false)
                .setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData).setHeaderWidth(50);

        // column groups
        CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder col_type = ctab.columnGroup("branch", String.class).setTotalHeader("Total quantity")
                .setShowTotal(true).setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData);

        // measure
        CrosstabMeasureBuilder quantityMeasure = ctab.measure("", "amount", Double.class, Calculation.NOTHING).setTitleStyle(stl.style().setFontSize(0));

        CrosstabBuilder crosstab = ctab.crosstab()
                .setCellWidth(220)
                .addHeaderCell(cmp.horizontalList(
                        cmp.text("Product").setStyle(headerStyleCenter).setFixedWidth(120),
                        cmp.text("Unit").setStyle(headerStyleCenter).setFixedWidth(50),
                        cmp.text("Year").setStyle(headerStyleCenter).setFixedWidth(50)).
                        setHeight(13))
                .setCellStyle(rowStyleData).setCellWidth(60)
                .rowGroups(rowGroupItem, rowGroupUnit, rowGroupDate)
                .columnGroups(col_type)
                .measures(quantityMeasure)
                .setDataPreSorted(true);

        // data
        List<ProductQuantityData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        int rowOrder = 1;
        int colOrder = 1;
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "2016.02", "Branch 1", 50d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "2017.02", "Branch 1", 150d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "diff", "Branch 1", 100d, rowOrder, colOrder));

        colOrder = 2;
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "2016.02", "Branch 2", 150d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "2017.02", "Branch 2", 140d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Water", "litre", "diff", "Branch 2", -10d, rowOrder, colOrder));

        rowOrder = 2;
        colOrder = 1;
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "2016.02", "Branch 1", 80d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "2017.02", "Branch 1", 75d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "diff", "Branch 1", -5d, rowOrder, colOrder));

        colOrder = 2;
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "2016.02", "Branch 2", 77d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "2017.02", "Branch 2", 77d, rowOrder, colOrder));
        dataList.add(new ProductQuantityData("Coffee bean", "kg", "diff", "Branch 2", 0d, rowOrder, colOrder));

        // sort
        SortBuilder rowSortBuilder = asc(field("rowOrder", Integer.class));
        SortBuilder columnSortBuilder = asc(field("colOrder", Integer.class));

        report
                .sortBy(rowSortBuilder, columnSortBuilder)
                .setPageFormat(PageType.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE)
                .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
                .title(Components.text("Product quantity by branch"))
                .summary(crosstab)
                .pageFooter(Components.pageXslashY())
                .setDataSource(new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList));

        return report;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CrosstabGroupTest design = new CrosstabGroupTest();
        try {
            JasperReportBuilder report = design.build();
            report.show();
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my java bean code:

```
public class ProductQuantityData {

    private String product;
    private String unit;
    private String date;

    private String branch;
    private Double amount;

    private int rowOrder;
    private int colOrder;

    public ProductQuantityData(String product, String unit, String date, String branch, Double amount, int rowOrder, int colOrder) {
        this.product = product;
        this.date = date;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.rowOrder = rowOrder;
        this.colOrder = colOrder;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getRowOrder() {
        return rowOrder;
    }

    public void setRowOrder(int rowOrder) {
        this.rowOrder = rowOrder;
    }

    public int getColOrder() {
        return colOrder;
    }

    public void setColOrder(int colOrder) {
        this.colOrder = colOrder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily found one helpful [forum post](http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=884&p=3019&hilit=row%20sort&sid=b923ad08578ce4025fe5fa5e3949cca8#p3019).

Add the following 2 classes.

```
    public class CTOValueFormatter extends AbstractValueFormatter<String, String>{
        @Override
        public String format(String value, ReportParameters reportParameters) {
           return value.split("-")[1];
        }
    }

    public class CTOrderExpression extends AbstractComplexExpression<String> {

        public CTOrderExpression(String sortField, String showField) {
            addExpression(field(sortField, Integer.class));
            addExpression(field(showField, String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public String evaluate(List<?> list, ReportParameters rp) {
            return list.get(0) + "-" + list.get(1);
        }
    }
```

And do not use `.sortBy(rowSortBuilder, columnSortBuilder)` and `.setDataPreSorted(true)`.

Instead create a row-group-item with the following code.

```
CrosstabRowGroupBuilder<String> rowGroupItem = ctab.rowGroup(new CTOrderExpression("rowOrder", "product")).setShowTotal(false)
    .setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData)
    .setHeaderWidth(120)
    .setHeaderValueFormatter(new CTOValueFormatter());
```

Also you can do same for the column-groups.

```
CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder col_type = ctab.columnGroup(new CTOrderExpression("colOrder", "branch")).setTotalHeader("Total quantity")
            .setShowTotal(true).setHeaderStyle(rowStyleData);
```

Grab the full source code [here](https://gist.github.com/Enkuushka/acd95d7174858ab4d7e107310a2f59f5).